# Oracle procedure to increase a value to below set amount

Tags: oracle

I wish to create a stored procedure that can be called to increase a staff member's salary by an amount passed in. It should firstly create a savepoint and then check that the new salary is below a set threshold and rollback to the savepoint if it is above the threshold.

```
-- Raise the Salary of the Staff memeber passed in by the amount specified
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RAISE (Selection IN Staff.StaffID%TYPE, amount IN Number)
  IS
  BEGIN
   SAVEPOINT save;
   UPDATE Staff 
   -- increase the salary by amount
   SET Staff.Salary =  (Staff.Salary + amount)
   -- Where StaffID is the one passed in
   WHERE Staff.StaffID = Selection;

   -- If the new value for salary is greater than 100000
   IF ( (Staff.Salary) > 100000 )
   -- Rollback and undo the changes
   THEN ROLLBACK TO save;
   -- Print out a message stating this is against business rules etc...
 END IF;
END;
/
```

The code above gives me back the following error:

[image: Screenshot of cmd output of error message]

I have tried the above code with `(:NEW.Salary > 100000)` but that gives me a bad bind error on New.Salary.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I think I could most probably replicate this functionality by just having a trigger before alter on the staff table, but why is it that the above code doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why make the change and then roll it back? I would simply not make the update in the first place if it doesn't match the criterion.

Comment: Neither would I to be honest, its for a project and one of the criteria is a procedure which utilises savepoint and rollback and I can't think of a better one. Which is why I had to invent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a procedure to create the save and to raise the salary, and then a function, which checks the salary passed in against the threshold and returns either 0 or 1 to the procedure, which then rollsback to the earlier save if necessary.

```
-- Raise the Salary of the Staff memeber passed in by the amount specified
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Raise1 (Selection IN Staff.StaffID%TYPE, amount IN Number)
-- Procedure that takes in StaffID and an amount to increase the staff salary by
IS
BEGIN
  SAVEPOINT save;
   UPDATE Staff 
   -- increase the salary by amount
    SET Staff.Salary =  (Staff.Salary + amount)
    -- Where StaffID is the one passed in
    WHERE Staff.StaffID = Selection;
    -- Pass control to the chekraise procedure, which will rollback to the 
    -- SAVEPOINT created above if the wage is above 100000 in accordance with business rules
    IF ( CheckRaise(Selection) = 0)
    THEN
    ROLLBACK TO save;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Reverted Raise as wage exceeded 100000.');
     END IF;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE Function CheckRaise (Selection IN Staff.StaffID%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
  -- Create a variable, to hold the salary we're checking
  Sal NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    -- Select the Staff.Salary that was just passed in into the sal variable
    SELECT Staff.Salary INTO Sal FROM Staff WHERE Staff.StaffID = Selection;
    -- If sal is above threshold
    IF (Sal >= 100000) 
    THEN
      -- Return 0, which the procedure will interpret as "Rollback"
      RETURN 0;
    ELSIF (Sal < 100000)
    THEN
      RETURN 1;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Uh oh Error - '||SQLCODE||' Unexpected error     '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```